# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Am building an app in ionic2 and whenever i load my data am getting this error

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

This is my component

```
export class TrackingcenterPage implements OnInit {

    constructor(public _navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    private _truckService:TruckService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {   // tried using OnInit but ionic complains and needs ngOnInit
        this.onGettrucks();
    }

    onGettrucks() {
        return this._truckService.getTrucks()
        .subscribe(res=>console.log(res), err=>console.log(err))
    }
}
```

In the truck service i have

```
@Injectable()
export class TruckService {
    trucksurl = this._domaindetails.getUrl() +"/rest/v1/truck/";

    getTrucks():Observable<any> {
        return this._httpClient.get(this.trucksurl+"trucks")
        .map(res=>res.json().data)
   }
```

In the truck service i have imported

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
```

I have also tried replacing OnInit event with `onPageLoaded`but it also fails

Comment: Is the call working? ( `.get(this.trucksurl+"trucks")`) Is `res.json().data` null or undefined?

Comment: What does your network tab say?

Comment: is `_httpClient` a custom provider?